# Print what is not in a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I have a join table created from 2 other tables.

Say one model is called cat, another is called request, and the join table is called catrequest (this table would have cat_id and request_id)

How would I print all of the cats not intersected in the join table i.e. all of the cats NOT requested using rails. I saw some DB based answers, but I am looking for a rails solution using ruby code.

I get how to print a cat that belongs to a request i.e.:

```
<% @requests.each do |request| %>
  <% request.cats.each do |cat| %>
    <%= cat.name %>
<% end %>
```

but I don't understand how to do the reverse of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a list of cats that have never been requested you'd go with:

```
Cat.includes(:cat_requests).where(cat_requests: { id: nil })
# or, if `cat_requests` table does not have primary key (id):
Cat.includes(:cat_requests).where(cat_requests: { cat_id: nil })
```

The above assumes you have the corresponding association:

```
class Cat
  has_many :cat_requests
end
```

Comment: The OP mentions that he's working with a join table in addition to the cats and requests tables. Will this still work?

Comment: @jaydel yes it will :)

Comment: This solution should also be implemented *outside* of the view

Comment: @whodini9 absolutely, it goes without saying :)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that if someone else tries this and is getting an id error. I don't think rails adds a primary key default (maybe I'm wrong) so you may need to modify the code to something like:Cat.includes(:cat_requests).where(cat_requests: {cat_id: nil}) since cat_id is on the join table.

Comment: @codingdraculasbrain I think you're getting the error because `cat_requests` does not have a primary key itself? (But for this there should be an option in migration, that creates the table saying something like `id: false`)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you need is an outer join, and then to thin out the cats rows that don't have corresponding data for the requests? If that's the case, you might consider using Arel. It supports an outer join and can probably be used to get what you're looking for. Here is a link to a guide that has a lot of helpful information on Arel:

http://jpospisil.com/2014/06/16/the-definitive-guide-to-arel-the-sql-manager-for-ruby.html

Search the page for "The More the Merrier" section which is where joins are discussed.

Comment: while I think my answer is still valid, Andrey's answer below is by far the better one.